# Как подсчитать количество записей в цепочке?

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня ессть упрощенная таблица перемещения пассажирских поездов, которые показывают его перемещение из города в город:

```sql
create table testt (
    ID NUMBER,
    VALST VARCHAR2(255),
    VALEND VARCHAR2(255),
    NEXTID NUMBER
)

   ID VALST  VALEND NEXTID
----- ----- ------- ------
    1   MOS     SAN      2
    2   SAN     MOS      
    3   MOS     EKB      4
    4   EKB     RYA      5
    5   RYA     SAN      6
    6   SAN     MOS      
    7   MOS     KRA      8
    8   KRA     VOR      9
    9   VOR     MOS
```

Работает она следующим образом: В ячейке `VALST` показано, откуда выезжает поезд, в `VALEND` - куда он приезжает. В ячейке `NEXTID` написан идентификатор следующего рейса. То есть, например, по ID 1 поезд поедет сначала из MOS в SAN, затем, в следующем рейсе под ID 2 он поедет из SAN в MOS, и цепочка на этом закончится, так как нет следующего идентификатора.

Задача состоит в следующем: определить количество рейсов в цепочке, то есть, когда поезд выезжает из MOS, и в итоге возвращается в MOS.

В примере сверху из ID 1 размер цепочки будет равен два, а из ID 3 цепочка будет равна четырем.

Пробовал через функцию LEAD, но, к сожалению, не получилось, прошу помощи.

Comment: LEAD тут не помощник. Используй рекурсию (CTE).

Comment: _Пробовал через функцию LEAD_, всегда дабавляте попытку решения, даже если она неверная. а) Проще  понять вашу задачу. б) Вопросы с попыткой решения чаще плюсуются, заработаете репутацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данные представляют собой обратную иерархию (*reverse hierarchy*).

Решатся простым [иерархическим запросом](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E) (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7902cacbfdbb1e8b2d4bca57a76a80f6)):

```
select valst, level numoftrips, sys_connect_by_path (valst, ' >> ') trips
from testt t
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with nextid is null 
connect by nextid = prior id
```

Результат:

```
VALST  NUMOFTRIPS TRIPS                            
------ ---------- --------------------------------
MOS             2  >> SAN >> MOS                  
MOS             4  >> SAN >> RYA >> EKB >> MOS    
MOS             3  >> VOR >> KRA >> MOS
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто и понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это выглядит в MySQL (извини, для ORACLE не стал делать, там сущее мучение с вводом данных в fiddle, а за диагностику проблем так и вовсе руки оторвать, но выглядеть будет практически так же):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT ID, VALST, VALEND, NEXTID, 1 AS length, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) chain
          FROM testt
          WHERE NEXTID IS NULL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT testt.ID, testt.VALST, cte1.VALEND, testt.NEXTID, cte1.length + 1, cte1.chain
          FROM testt
          JOIN cte1 ON testt.NEXTID = cte1.ID ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY chain ORDER BY length DESC) rn
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT ID, VALST, length 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a41425e1b0c3cb532c410351a95f8ace